# How to ping a static ip from a remote desktop connection in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I'm looking for a way to ping an IP address of a device connected to a remote server through ethernet port.

I'm able to establish connection with the remote server through remotedesktopClient, but is there a way to ping the device ip through the RDP connection?

Please help.

Below is my code, I'm not finding a way through RDP to ping the IP address.

Is there any other way to connect to remote system and then through its connect ping the ip address? Here the remote system is a Windows OS system.

```
var remoteDesktopClient = new MsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting();
remoteDesktopClient.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 0;
remoteDesktopClient.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
remoteDesktopClient.Server = "remotesystem hostname";

remoteDesktopClient.UserName = "myusername";
remoteDesktopClient.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = "mypwd";

remoteDesktopClient.Connect();
```

Comment: RDC is not a VPN protocol.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something like psexec (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)